# cannot align subplots when plotting geopandas dataframes

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I am attempting to plot a geopandas dataframe of bus stops (shapely points over another dataframe of a shape file (polygon). I can plot them individually, but when I attempt to layer them, I cannot get the plots to line up correctly.

```py
# Convert the dataframe into a geodataframe
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(unique_stops.drop(['lat', 'lng'], axis=1), crs={'init': 'esri:102003'}, geometry=[Point(xy) for xy in zip(unique_stops.lat, unique_stops.lng)])

# read in the city shapefile
base = gpd.read_file('https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/89f1a70c0cf24d7692e2d02fdf8f4e47_0.geojson')
base.to_crs(crs={'init': 'esri:102003'}, inplace=True)

# Setup figure and axis with different size
f, ax = plt.subplots(1)

# Add layer of polygons on the axis
base.plot(ax=ax)
gdf.plot(ax=ax)

# Display
plt.show()
```

I expect the plots to be layered on top of each other. However, the output is currently as follows:

[image]

I believe this may be because the x an y axes of the dataframe geometries might be reversed from each other, but I cannot figured out how to specify that explicitly.

Comment: I would rather guess that the data is specified in totally different coordinate systems (similar to how a sine wave is different between radiants and degrees). Mostly, when plotting geo data one would use a transform, but one cannot know if this is missing here, since the example is not a [mcve].

Comment: I think you should switch longitude and latitude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed an issue of lat,lons being reversed as well as mismatching CRS.